# Condition under which the Clarke's subdifferential is locally Lipschitzian

Tags: derivatives, weak-derivatives, non-smooth-analysis, non-smooth-optimization

Given a locally Lipschitz continuous function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. The Clarke's subdifferential set is the set given by
$$ 
\partial f (x) = {\text{cl co}}\left\lbrace \lim_{k\in\mathbb{N}} \nabla f (x^{k}) \ |\  \text{whenever }  x^{k} \rightarrow x^{*} \text{ and } \lim_{k\in\mathbb{N}} \nabla f (x^{k}) \text{ exist} \right\rbrace
.$$ My question is about the context in which this multivalued function satisfies a weak notion of locally Lipschitz continuity for multifunctions; by that I mean that for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ there exist $L$ and $ \delta > 0 $ such that for all $y,z \in B(x,\delta)$ it holds
$$
d(\partial f (y), \partial f (z)) = \inf_{g\in \partial f (y)} \inf_{g' \in \partial f (z) } \|g - g'\| < L \|y-z\|. 
$$ Note that when the function is locally Fréchet differentiable with continuous second derivative, this is true. It seems to be true for all functions sufficiently regular. It might be true for piecewise smooth functions with sufficiently regular set of discontinuity of the derivative. Is there a good context in which this is true?